# Is there any easier ways to find cats in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I've been playing a lot of minecraft recently, (I play on pe) and I got the update where they added bamboo, cats, pandas, and scaffolding. Cats now appear in villiges and witch huts, but when I searched for a village using /locate village , It said that the closest village was at 12264 (y?) 148. Is there any easier ways to find them? (oh yeah and my server doesn't have ANY jungles :()

Comment: Well.. if that is the closest village, did you trying teleporting to those coordinates and seeing if it was one?

Comment: @KyleRone yes I did, and there was a village there, but I wanted to go there without teleporting (I'm less worried about the locate cheat than the teleport cheat.) Also, I'm afraid If I go there, I might lose my house again, because it's so far away.

Comment: I don't know how to do it on PE, but there should be a way to see your current coordinates.  Constantly knowing where you are and where you want to be will let you navigate to that place.

Comment: @MBraedley there is, but you have to turn it on before you create the world, because after, you can't turn it on, and I would make a map, but for an infinate world on pe, it only shows a portion of the world.

Comment: Really?  That seems a little odd.  Is there no debug display like there is in the Java version?

Comment: @MBraedley nope. No debug display, although there are mods of it, but I don't use mods for my games.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get cats is to play in creative mode. Build a huge fence area. Then in the eggs list you should find ocelot eggs as one of the egg items. After throwing your desired amount of ocelot eggs equip fish and crouch toward the animal after a while the ocelot should be tamed and will turn into a random cat type.